# Django - model have date in string 'MM/DD/YYYY' how can I order_by(date) in this situation?

Tags: python, django, date

I have models with date information in string in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format. I would like to make a query of this models and order them by this date.

But in order to do it I will need to convert this date to format readable by django. I know that I could add additional field to my model and make a script that would fill this field with datetime format but I would like to do it (if possible) while making query, since this won't be used much.

Once I solved similar problem by using this kind of code:

```
sorted(information, key=lambda k: pendulum.from_format(k['date'], 'MMMM DD, YYYY'))
```

`pendulum.from_format` in `sorted()` let me do this 'on the fly' in one line. I am wondering If I could somehow incorporate in django `order_by()` this `pendulum.from_format`?

Comment: Why do you use a string for datetime formatting? Please use a `DateField`.

Comment: I am using string because I am importing it from external json. In this json date is just a  'MM/DD/YYYY' string. Do you mean that If I would import this date string into 'DateField' then it would be working "out of the box" ?

Comment: I would really advise to do the transformation before you store it in the database, so preprocessing the result you retrieve from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You should save every date information using the Django date format in the `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_date = models.DateField()
```

Then you can easily save it (e.g. in the logic of your `view.py`)

```
from datetime import datetime
try:
    input_date = datetime.strptime(my_record, '%d %m, %Y')
    instance.my_date = input_date
    instance.save()
except ValueError:
    print("format not valid")
```

or call it using a Django `queryset` (so that you can also sort it easily).

Moreover, if you have a form somewhere, you are also able to validate the field in `forms.py`

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=YOUR_DATE_INPUT_FORMAT)
```